# Wrapping all methods of a controller in Recess

Tags: php, recess

In recess, I have a controller

```
/**

 * !RespondsWith Layouts

 * !Prefix user/

 */

class UserController extends Controller 

{
......
}
```

I want to wrap all methods of the UserController using Iwrapper. I know how to wrap method of a normal class using IWrapper. But in the case of the controller, i 'm not being able to do it because the UserController is not instantiated and its methods are called automatically by the recess controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotations to add a wrapper to the controller class. For instance, I have a controller "nas"

```
/**
 * !RespondsWith Json,CSV
 * !Prefix nas/
 */
 class NasController extends Controller {

     /** 
      * !Route GET
      * !VerifyPermission Module: data, Permission: read, UnauthorizedAction: noEntry
      */
      function index() {
      }
 }
```

The VerifyPermission annotation will add a wrapper in the expand method

```
Library::import('recess.lang.Annotation');
Library::import('cirrusWorks.wrappers.VerifyPermissionWrapper');

class VerifyPermissionAnnotation extends Annotation {

    protected function expand($class, $reflection, $descriptor) {
        $module = $this->module;
        $permission = $this->permission;
        $unauthorizedAction = $this->unauthorizedaction;

        $descriptor->addWrapper('serve',new VerifyPermissionWrapper($module,$permission,$unauthorizedAction, $reflection->getName()));
        /* ... */
        return $descriptor;
    }
 }
```

Then you can create the VerifyPermissionWrapper and the standard methods will be wrapped around your class method (before(), after(), combine())

```
class VerifyPermissionWrapper implements IWrapper {
    function __construct($module, $permission, $action, $method) {
        $this->module = $module;
        $this->permission = $permission;
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    function before($controller, &$args) {
        error_log('Before {$this->action} on {$this->method}');
    }
}
```